# I would like to merge one data frame with each vector in a list of vectors.. Output should be a list of data frames

Tags: r

```
str(list) # the list
List of 11
 $ : int [1:62850] 1013128473 1010310348 1048245573 1034384956 1041152164 1044038741 1018034270 1028472668 1028965885 1009487677 ...
 $ : int [1:76934] 1013175201 1008463364 1016595579 1015077603 1036297925 1033985605 1004670509 1002708962 1035740487 1033948421 ...
 $ : int [1:63141] 1023522277 1028419750 1035072196 1015895913 1044665345 1045384789 1003817549 1007103029 1034294940 1048731747 ...
 $ : int [1:66286] 1004375117 1015143512 1013554405 1029388459 1042758662 1002010773 1014659880 1010136990 1042787992 1034111995 ...
 $ : int [1:59295] 1026598712 1046781801 1047773468 1029647490 1000445831 1004654396 1026574333 1028210894 1031396631 1017077460 ...
 $ : int [1:39513] 1008628321 1031342452 1036618138 1025299916 1059540334 1044636981 1025831775 1020671796 1016064196 1000573822 ...
 $ : int [1:52616] 1007104357 1035072196 1045300736 1013342439 1021471188 1014648594 1047521123 1006283327 1018237501 1052887674 ...
 $ : int [1:53865] 1043482304 1006375883 1065831792 1025658285 1025898360 1042188555 1010986410 1036297925 1016468595 1042017564 ...
 $ : int [1:74030] 1049026709 1076616323 1013343981 1009441716 1004974596 1032515221 1059905172 1011514112 1005423064 1006931636 ...
 $ : int [1:62171] 1024128835 1006168791 1003374715 1042188555 1016219766 1002708962 1035781234 1039706286 1011430434 1055809196 ...
 $ : int [1:66560] 1020967137 1029327077 1026256246 1046334023 1035156221 1017504075 1035065786 1043426434 1034294940 1019105475 ...

str(df) # the data frame
'data.frame':   3727518 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A: int  10001676 10001676 10002575 10002990 10003466 10005485 10005736 10005949 10006562 10007119 ...
 $ 1: int  1020565642 1020565642 1008628321 1038358741 1045031612 1025102185 1011873328 1002079752 1028579827 1026598712 ...
 $ 2: Factor w/ 2 levels "ÇäËì","ÐßÑ": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ 3: int  1 4 1 1 1 1 20 1 1 1 ...
 $ 4: int  64 64 66 63 69 59 84 83 65 64 ...
```

I want to merge each vector in the list with the data frame by "A".

What I tried was:

```
for(n in 1:length(list)) 
{
  newlist[[n]] <- merge(df, list[[n]], by.x = "A")
}

Error in merge.data.frame(rd_info, newengagementspermonth[[n]], by.x = "NEWNINUMBER") : 
  'by.x' and 'by.y' specify different numbers of columns
```

The input is a list of 11 vectors and a dataframe. the output should be a list of 11 dataframes with the each dataframe having number of rows equal to the length of the corresponding vector.

Comment: Use by ="A", or by.x="A" and by.y="A". And for the moment you will only get one data.frame, namely the last one from list merged with df.

Comment: I really think this does not make sense at all. In a vector is no data to merge... You would just reduce your data frame to the indices you have in the list. You also overwrite you `newlist` in this way, so at least use `newlist[[n]] <- ...`.

Comment: thats right I want to reduce the data frame to the indices in each list.. multiple times for each vector.. to obtain a list of 11 data frames

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. First, explicitly transform each object in the list into a data.frame. Then, merge it with df. You need to specify `by.x` and `by.y` since the data.frames do not have the same names.

```
new list <- lapply(lapply(list,as.data.frame),function(x) merge(x,df,by.x="X[[i]]",by.y="A",all.x=TRUE))
```

With sample data:

```
list <- list(1:8,1:10,2:15)
df <- data.frame(A=1:15,
             b=rnorm(15))
```

output

```
str(newlist)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':   8 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X[[i]]: int [1:8] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  ..$ b     : num [1:8] 0.0127 0.2082 -0.271 0.421 -0.538 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X[[i]]: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ b     : num [1:10] 0.0127 0.2082 -0.271 0.421 -0.538 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   14 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X[[i]]: int [1:14] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
  ..$ b     : num [1:14] 0.208 -0.271 0.421 -0.538 0.506 ...
```